# In EXCEL, how would I compare multiple values and print their connections into a corresponding field?

Tags: excel

I have a master list of inventory numbers in column A.
I have a master list of corresponding image links in column B.

In column C, I have a smaller list of product numbers (from the master list) that need their image edited.

I'd like to take the number from column C, find the same number in column A, then have the formula spit out the corresponding image into column D.

I should wind up with a small list of image links, and then I can do the editing and re-upload without having to do the monotonous repetition.

I've googled this concept, but I can't seem to find an answer that I can work with.  I know it's out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `VLOOKUP` like this in cell D1:

```
=VLOOKUP(C1, A:B, 2, FALSE)
```

And drag the formula down.

This takes the value of C1, looks for it in column A, and returns the corresponding value from the 2nd column, that is B. `FALSE` means exact match.

---

EDIT: To get a new masterlist but with the updated image links, you can try this formula in cell L1:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, E:F, 2, 0), B1)
```

And drag the formula down to as far as the column A has product IDs.

Comment: That worked great!  I've edited the images now, and I'm moving right along.

Comment: If I have a product ID in Column E and an edited image address in Column F, how could I find the numbers in Column A that match Column E and then take the data from Column F and put it into Column L?

Comment: @user2803472 Hmm, I'm not sure I understand the purpose of this one. Since column A is the master list, all product IDs from column E will match those from column A, and therefore, it will be easier to simply copy column F to column L?

Comment: Column A is the master list, but column E is a smaller list of items from Column A that needed editing.  Now I need to replace the edited data from column F into column L (where the original data that needed editing resides).   I want to use the value Column E to select the particular row in Column A that corresponds to the column E value - then take the Column F value and dump it into Column L.

Comment: I'm working on a workaround, but I'm not quite there yet.  I appreciate the effort, I hope my explanation made sense, it looks like a big block of misdirection.

Comment: @user2803472 Oh! You want to get a new masterlist, but with updated image list? Then you can use `IFERROR()`. I'll put it in my answer because the comments usually mess up excel formulae :)

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I need to sit down and read up on Excel's methods.  I procrastinate doing it until I need something serious done quickly, and then I get on here.  I'm taking my first programming courses at school, Java and JavaScript.  The logic makes a lot of sense, I just don't know the syntax.  Thanks again.